# Real and complex analysis 3.4. (c), (d)

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a complex measurable function on $X$, $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X$, and

$\varphi(p)=\int_{X}|f|^{p} d \mu=\|f\|_{p}^{p} \quad(0<p<\infty)$

Let $E=\{p: \varphi(p)<\infty\} . \text { Assume }\|f\|_{\infty}>0$

I have two questions

(1)
I want to show that $E$ is not necessarily closed. Therefore, I assume that $X = (0,1), f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

$$\int_X |f|^p d\mu= \int_{(0,1)}\frac{1}{x^p}dx = \lim_{a\to 0}\int_a^b(\frac{1}{x^p})dx + \lim_{c\to 0}\int_b^c(\frac{1}{x^p})dx = -\lim_{a\to 0}a^{1-p} - \lim_{c\to 1}c^{1-p}  = -1$$ if $p < 1$

Is my solution correct?

(2)
I want to show that

$\text { If } r<p<s, \text { prove that }\|f\|_{p} \leq \max \left(\|f\|_{r},\|f\|_{s}\right) \text { . }$

I showed that $\phi(p) \le \phi(r)^{\lambda}\phi(s)^{1-\lambda}$ for $0 \le \lambda \le 1$.
Therefore, $\|f\|_{p}^p \leq \|f\|_{r}^{r/2}\|f\|_{s}^{s/2}$ when $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$.

I don't know how to proceed the next part.

Would you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), you showed that $E = (0,1)$, and you are right that this is not closed and so it's a valid counterexample.

For (2), it seems like you are there. I think you can do cases?. In the first case, suppose that $\phi(r) \geq \phi(s)$ and in the second case suppose the opposite. Square root is monotonic, so you could square root and then just plug in the bigger one and get the desired result. Or, in other words, note that

$$||||^{/2}_ \leq \max(||||^{/2}_,||||^{s/2}_s) $$
and
$$||||^{/2}_ \leq \max(||||^{/2}_,||||^{s/2}_s).$$